# Probability to get from A to C.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

There has been a snowstorm and Bob is trying to drive from A to C.

p and q are the probabilities that the two roads are passable. 
What is the probability that Bob can get from A to C? Note that whether the 2 roads are passable/ not passable are independent

$ \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:p\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:q$

A ------------------B-----------------------C

So, this is my attempt:

From A to B , we have probability of $P(p)$

From B to C , we have probability of $P(q)$

Hence $P(AC) = P(p)\cap P(q) \rightarrow P(p)P(q)$ by independence.

We can also do the following analysis:

$p$ can be denoted by $1-p^{\complement}$ where $p^{\complement}$ is the probability A to B not passable.

$q$ can be denoted by $1-q^{\complement}$ where $p^{\complement}$ is the probability B to C not passable.

Hence. we can denote $P(AC) = (1-p^{\complement})(1-q^{\complement})$

Then factor it out.$1-(p^{\complement}+q^{\complement})+(p^{\complement}q^{\complement})$

Can it be simplified further? And is this analysis sound? Appreciate feedback thanks.

Comment: Sorry...isn't $p$ is the probability that road $AB$ is open, and $q$ is the probability that road $BC$ is open?  Why should those add to $1$?  On a good day, I'd hope they added to $2$!

Comment: Omg! u're right!!

Comment: If my understanding of what $p,q$ are is correct, then the answer is just $pq$, no?

Comment: That's what I thought! But it seems to simple.. hmm

Comment: Your analysis is correct, but the statement "Note that whether the 2 roads are passable/ not passable are independent" seems a little unrealistic.